# How can I create an Entity automatically, which has a one-to-one-not-optional-relationship to the Entity I'm creating?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

How can I create an Entity automatically, which has a one-to-one-not-optional-relationship to the Entity I'm creating with:

```
NSManagedObject *managedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

I can't find an answer to that. My Workaround is to set the relationship to "optional".  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `newEntityDescription` is wrong. you're creating an `NSMananagedObject`, not an `NSEntityDescription`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the property after creating the new instance. Validation rules (e.g. whether a relationship is optional, etc.) are only enforced on save, though you can test them earlier with certain methods. This means you can create the object, set up the properties and relationships, and then save. So in this case, you'd probably want something like

```
NSManagedObject *newObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];
[newObject setValue:entity forKey:@"relationship"];
// now the object should be valid when you call save
```